# Azure Functions On-Prem Setup Guidance

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm evaluating azure functions on-prem and would like to have the manager and worker roles separated. The install docs go through a scenario where both roles are on the same machine.

Does this mean that separating the roles on different VMs would not be supported/recommended?

If this is acceptable, would nested virtualization only be required on the worker VM since that's where the containers are spun up?

Is it common practice or even reasonable to use a role-based database prefix like "worker_" and "manager_"?

Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot just install the manager in a role but what you can do is install many more workers on other machines, as mentioned in the documentation.  To deploy additional workers just run the installer and choose the option Functions Worker Role and that will only install the functions worker on that machine.

In the preview, we install everything on one machine to get folks up and running quickly.  This is good feedback to hear though.

Regarding the role-based prefix I'm not sure I understand your goal, there is only one database and that is for the whole of Functions Runtime preview and it is used by the management role, we do not create a separate database per worker.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew! With regard to the role based prefix, that was asked out of a bit of confusion on my part.